# Whats wrong with my code? I don't get an error; I get no response what so ever

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I don't uderstand what's wrong with my code...

USAGE:

/suggest

bot sends suggestion to channel named sugestions
Here's meh code:

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}suggest`){

  // USAGE: 
  // /suggest this is the suggestion

  let suggestion = args.join(" ").slice(22);

  let suggestEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setDescription("~~-------~~**__NEW SUGGESTION!__**~~-------~~")
  .setColor("#ff0000")
  .addField("Suggestion By", `${message.author} (${message.author.id})`)
  .addField("Channel", message.channel)
  .addField("Time", message.createdAt)
  .addField("Suggestion", suggestion)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter("Use /invite to invite me to your server!");

  let suggestchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "suggestions");
  if(!suggestchannel) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find suggestions channel. Please **create one for this command to work!**");


  message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
  suggestchannel.send(suggestEmbed);

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake with your codeline `suggestchannel.send(...)`. You can't send an embed as **message content** because this **has to be a string**. 
Here you can find more informations regarding this: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send

**This is the corrected code, try to use the following:**

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}suggest`) {
    // USAGE:
    // /suggest this is the suggestion

    const suggestion = args.join(' ').slice(22);

    const suggestEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription('~~-------~~**__NEW SUGGESTION!__**~~-------~~')
        .setColor('#ff0000')
        .addField('Suggestion By', `${message.author} (${message.author.id})`)
        .addField('Channel', message.channel)
        .addField('Time', message.createdAt)
        .addField('Suggestion', suggestion)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('Use /invite to invite me to your server!');

    const suggestchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, 'suggestions');
    if (!suggestchannel) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find suggestions channel. Please **create one for this command to work!**");


    message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
    suggestchannel.send({ embed: suggestEmbed });
}
```